# Run PHP file on web browser

Tags: php, xampp

I have a php file that does not want to open on my browser, I saved it in xammp/htdoc folder and when I try to open it in browser I get the option to either save or open the file.

This is my code:

```
<html>
 <body>
 <?php
 if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
 //if "email" is filled out, send email
   {
   //send email
   $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
   $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
   $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
   mail("my_email_address@yahoo.com", $subject,
   $message, "From:" . $email);
   echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
   }
 else
 //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
   {
       echo "<form method='post' action='sch.php'>
        Email: <input name='email' type='text'><br>
                 Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
   Message:<br>
   <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
   </textarea><br>
   <input type='submit'>
   </form>";
   }
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: A php script cannot be interpret by a browser. It typically requires an http server with a php extension executing it. Do you have such a server installed and running? If so, then open the script not by its local file path but by its url, something like http://localhost/.../script.php

Comment: Please note that your form is open to header injection and it wouldn't be hard to send millions of spam emails to people all around the world and get your server blocked from every sending mails again. `POST contact.php?email=foo@bar.com\r\nCc:president@whitehouse.gov,putin@russia.com`

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the file via the local webserver so that the php can be interpreted.

Provided appache is listening on port 80 localhost, you must have a url like this in your browser:

```
localhost/yourfile.php
```

NOT

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/yourfile.php
```